# How to add custom Admin/Host page to DotNetNuke?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I am working on building some custom functionality into a DNN (DotNetNuke) website via a custom module extension. I am needing to add a page that can be navigated to from the main 'Admin' and/or 'Host' menus when logged into DNN.

Could someone point me to any articles, or post code samples/descriptions on how to add a custom page to the 'Admin' and/or 'Host' menu within via a custom module extension?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this same question on the DotNetNuke forums and was directed with the following answer:

> As to creating the page, there is no longer anything special about pages under admin (in early DNN days, only admins could access them but this limitation was removed in dnn 3.0), so the advice at http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/create-a-new-page-programmatically will work with you just identifying the admin page as the parent page.
>
> However for admin pages, I'd suggest using a tabid rather than a fixed name (in case someone renames "admin" to something else) e.g. use PortalSettings.AdminTabid for the parented property when defining the tabid that you pass to tabcontroller.addtab(yournewtabinfo)

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/forumid/203/postid/498252/scope/posts#498252

Answer (score 1):

Just add the page as a child of Host or Admin depending you how you want to use it.  Then, add your custom module to the page (after installing the module from the Host, Extension page).